# 12.04.2 i386 gets downloaded instead of 13.04 amd64

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, downloads

I've been trying to download the latest release from the website, but even though I'm selecting 13.04 64-bit as my option, the download begins for 12.04.2 32-bit. Any ideas as why this is happening?
I'm downloading on Windows 8 in Dell Inspiron.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it easier on you, to download Ubuntu 13.04 64bit just click [Here](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases//raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso), and that will download the right file.

Answer (score 1):

When browsing to *"Get Ubuntu now-> Ubuntu Desktop"* on the main page for [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) you will be directed to a donation page. After having entered your choice you should be directed to the download page for Ubuntu

- [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

On this page you will have a choice for downloading Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, or further down on this page for Ubuntu 13.04, each having a dropbox to choose 32-bit (default), or 64-bit architecture:

[image]

If you do not see this page there may have been an error.

In this case, or to choose another download mirror or a BitTorrent download we will also have access to downloads from the following page:

- [Ubuntu Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Of course you will see download from various other non-official sources. This may work fine, but keep in mind to be carfeul to not download a customized version different to the official release.